# Drawing a smooth curve

Tags: java, android

I want to create more a smooth curve, not only line angles. This is the picture how I draw at the moment:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
case FREEHAND:
    float[] pts;
    float[] ptk;
    ptk = new float[2];
    imageMatrix.invert(inv);            
    if (mCurrentShape == null) {                
        mCurrentShape = new Line();
        pts = new float[2];
        ((Line) mCurrentShape).setBegin(mDownPoint);
        pts[0] = (float)((Line) mCurrentShape).getBegin().getX();
        pts[1] = (float)((Line) mCurrentShape).getBegin().getY();
        inv.mapPoints(pts);
        ((Line) mCurrentShape).getPath().moveTo(pts[0], pts[1]);
    }
    ptk[0] = (float)currentPoint.getX();
    ptk[1] = (float)currentPoint.getY();
    inv.mapPoints(ptk);
    ((Line) mCurrentShape).getPath().lineTo(ptk[0], ptk[1]);
    break;
```

Freehand code:

```
package aa.bb.cc;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.graphics.Path;

public class FreeHand extends Shape{
    private ArrayList<Path>_graphics;

    public FreeHand(){
        super();
        _graphics = new ArrayList<Path>();
    }

    public ArrayList<Path> getGraphicsPath(){
        return _graphics;
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at this: http://corner.squareup.com/2012/07/smoother-signatures.html it's not a complete solution, but it gives you an idea of what you can do.

Comment: This article about Bezier curves might be useful:
http://devmag.org.za/2011/04/05/bzier-curves-a-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

I have a code use quadratic Bezier line to smooth the points. Which turns out work really well. It is also very efficient.  Use the following class the construct your smoothed path. Each time you have a new point, use `addPoint(x, y)` to add it. Once you are done, you can call `constructPath()` to get the smoothed path. Compare to the solutions in the comments, like "corner.squareup.com/2012/07/smoother-signatures.html", my solution avoids the artifacts at the very sharp corners of the original path.

```
public class BezierCurveConstructor {
Path path;

PointF previousPoint;
int pointCounter = 0;

public BezierCurveConstructor() {
    reset();
}


/**
 * reset the path
 */
public void reset() {
    path = new Path();
    pointCounter = 0;
}


public void addPoint(float x, float y) {

    pointCounter ++;
    if (pointCounter == 1) {
        path.moveTo(x, y);
        previousPoint = new PointF(x, y);
        return;
    }


    PointF mid = new PointF((x + previousPoint.x) / 2.0f, (y + previousPoint.y) / 2.0f);

    if (pointCounter < 3) {
        path.lineTo(mid.x, mid.y);
    } else {
        path.quadTo(previousPoint.x, previousPoint.y, mid.x, mid.y);
    }
    previousPoint = new PointF(x, y);
}

/**
 * construct path by points
 *
 * @return
 */
public Path constructPath() {
    return path;
}
```

}

This path contains a list of quadratic Bezier curves going through all the middle points of the previous point and the next points of your touches. Note that this path has constant second derivatives but the first derivatives match at the glue points. We can show why it is so by the following derivation:

`Denote the list of points as p_0, p_1, ... p_n, (these can be points in R^n)
let c_i = (pi+p_{i_1})/2 as the middle point of pi and p_{i-1}.
We can model the quadratic Bezier line as following, here t is a number between 0 and 1:
G_i(t)=(1-t)^2c_i +2(1-t)tp_i + t^2 c_{i+1}
Consider the derivative against t:
G_i'(t) = -2(1-t)c_i + 2(1-t-t)p_i + 2t c_{i+1}, and 
G_i''(t) = 2c_i -4p_i + 2c_{i+1} = 2p_{i-1} + 2 p_{i+1}
Thus the second derivatives are constants. To show that the 
first derivatives match at each c_i, we can plug in t=0, and t=1.
G_i'(0) = 2p_i-2c_i = p_i - p_{i-1}
G_{i-1}'(1) = -2p_{i-1}+2c_i = p_i - p_{i-1} = G_i'(0)`

BTW, you can have a look at wiki for a clear definition of a Bezier curve https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve

Checkout this link for the raw code:
https://github.com/lyang36/codeNotes/blob/master/BezierCurveConstructor.java